# Spring AbstractPdfView display already created pdf in the browser

Tags: java, spring, pdf, io

I have 2 pdf files already created.  They are in the following folder `WebContent/pdf/`

I have extended Spring's AbstractPdfView before to make a pdf on the fly.

This time I want to use it to

1) display an already created pdf and
2) use itext to pass a model object to the second pdf and fill already created pdf form fields.

I know with 1) I can just create a link and access the pdf directly.  I was trying to access it via extending AbstractPdfView since I believe that I need to use that for case 2).

I am just not sure how to get the resource and then display it in the browser with this class.

Can anyone please show me how to accomplish this with a sample?

spring-pdf-views.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="BlankPDF" class="com.example.BlankPDF"/>
    <bean id="PopulatedPDF" class="com.example.PopulatedPDF"/>

</beans>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="xmlViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="location">
        <value>/WEB-INF/spring-pdf-views.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may actually want to subclass AbstractPdfStamperView instead:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/document/AbstractPdfStamperView.html

It looks like you set the "url" property of your AbstractPdfStamperView subclass to be the path to your existing PDF file:

```
<!-- PopulatedPDF extends AbstractPdfStamperView -->
<bean id="PopulatedPdf class="com.example.PopulatedPdf"> 
    <property name="url" value="/WEB-INF/pdfs/blankform.pdf" />
</bean>
```

Then you will need to override mergePdfDocument():

```
@Override
protected void mergePdfDocument(Map<String,Object> model,
                                     com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfStamper stamper,
                                     HttpServletRequest request,
                                     HttpServletResponse response)
                              throws Exception {

    // follow example code for filling out a form using iText:
    // http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=122

    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
    // form.setField("fieldName", model.get("fieldName"));
}
```

You probably will want to look at the iText PdfStamper docs to figure out what all your options are there.

http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/index.html?com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html

Comment: Thanks for the response but I have already viewed both these links before and I was asking about sample code.  I'm confused how to implement my scenerio.

Comment: I've tried to edit my answer with more actual code. Let me know if that's any more help.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.  I think I am pretty close but I am getting an error now with my configuration.  As soon as I changed my class to extend AbstractPdfStamperView I got the following error:

Comment: ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xmlViewResolver' defined in class path resource [spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PopulatedPDF' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-pdf-views.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'url' is required

Comment: Can you include the part of the spring-pdf-views.xml file where you define the 'PopulatedPDF' bean? And your bean definition for 'xmlViewResolver'?

Comment: I updated the original question with those two files at the bottom

Comment: I updated my answer. You have to set the "url" property of the views in the view bean xml file. It looks like with AbstractPdfStamperView you provide the path to the PDF file on the classpath for the "url" property. The view will then read that existing PDF, so I don't think you need to override readPdfResource() yourself after all.

Comment: @sdouglass, could you please look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/21914583/3287503 ? I am lost and have no idea how to solve it; your answer here could help but I don't know how to use it in my problem.