# JFreeChart not showing in generated Spring MVC and iText PDF

Tags: java, spring, pdf, itext, jfreechart

I asked before the question "[*Append PDF at the available space of another PDF file*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21899463/3287503)" and I have successfully made a PDF with both native iText and JFreeChart combined in one page.

I merged this setup to my Spring MVC application using the tutorial "[*Spring Web MVC with PDF View Example (using iText 5.x)*](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-web-mvc-with-pdf-view-example-using-itext-5x)".

I understand that using Spring's `AbstractView` and in turn implemented as

```
@Override
protected void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> map, Document document,
        PdfWriter pdfWriter, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // do iText and JFreeCharts

}
```

and that a JFreeChart instance needs an existing PDF file to be inserted into it as demonstrated in "[*Creating an iText pdf with embedded JFreeChart*](http://www.wirelust.com/2008/03/17/creating-an-itext-pdf-with-embedded-jfreechart/)":

```
// get the direct pdf content
PdfContentByte dc = docWriter.getDirectContent();

// get a pdf template from the direct content
PdfTemplate tp = dc.createTemplate(width, height);

// create an AWT renderer from the pdf template
Graphics2D g2 = tp.createGraphics(width, height, new DefaultFontMapper() );
Rectangle2D r2D = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0, width,height);
chart.draw(g2,r2D,null);
g2.dispose();

// add the rendered pdf template to the direct content
// you will have to play around with this because the chart is absolutely positioned.
// 38 is just a typical left margin
// docWriter.getVerticalPosition(true) will approximate the position that the content above the chart ended
dc.addTemplate(tp, 38, docWriter.getVerticalPosition(true)-height);
```

My problem now is that whenever I call the method that extends `AbstractView` (refer to the second link), **it shows the PDF before inserting the JFreeChart and not the one with the generated chart**. I haven't encountered any errors for this one but I would like to know if there is a solution for this behavior.

I just want the user to see the PDF with JFreeChart, just like a normal PDF implementation in Spring MVC.

As you can see I just followed the tutorials above and combined them. They worked perfectly in a separate project but when I merged with Spring, the JFreeChart is not showing, specifically the wrong PDF file is shown.

---

I know that I can just call the generated PDF with JFreeChart and somewhat intercept the viewing by putting a link to the correct file but I am keeping my hopes up with this setup because it would be a convenient way to use the three technologies altogether without the hassle of file I/O in server (which I have trouble in).

---

Below is a snippet of the class `AbstractITextPdfView` from "[*Spring Web MVC with PDF View Example (using iText 5.x)*](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-web-mvc-with-pdf-view-example-using-itext-5x)" that I use.

Can someone tell me how to direct the PDF file being opened to the one with the chart ie inside the `buildPdfDocument()`?

```
@Override
protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    // IE workaround: write into byte array first.
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = createTemporaryOutputStream();

    // Apply preferences and build metadata.
    Document document = newDocument();
    PdfWriter writer = newWriter(document, baos);
    prepareWriter(model, writer, request);
    buildPdfMetadata(model, document, request);

    // Build PDF document.
    document.open();
    buildPdfDocument(model, document, writer, request, response);
    document.close();

    // Flush to HTTP response.
    writeToResponse(response, baos);
}
```

---

### Update

I intercepted the `ByteArrayOutputStream` by saving in into a file after `JFreeChart` "attaches" itself to the `iText` PDF.

```
@Override
protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    // IE workaround: write into byte array first.
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = createTemporaryOutputStream();

    // Apply preferences and build metadata.
    Document document = newDocument();
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = newWriter(document, baos);
    prepareWriter(model, pdfWriter, request);
    buildPdfMetadata(model, document, request);

    // Build PDF document.
    document.open();
    buildPdfDocument(model, document, pdfWriter, request, response);
    document.close();

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/MUST-HAVE-CHART.pdf"));
        baos.writeTo(fos);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // Handle exception here
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        fos.close();
    }
    System.out.println(baos.toString());

    // Flush to HTTP response.
    writeToResponse(response, baos);
}
```

What happened is that `MUST-HAVE-CHART.PDF` does not have the chart, same as the one provided by Spring MVC after creation. The one with the chart however is saved somewhere else, as seen in the code:

```
@Override
protected void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> map, Document document,
        PdfWriter pdfWriter, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    logger.info("Start of PDF creation");

    Domain domain = (Domain) map.get("domain");

    ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession()
            .getServletContext();
    File servletTempDir = (File) servletContext
            .getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");

    if (servletTempDir == null)
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Container does not provide a temp dir");

    File targetFile = new File(servletTempDir, NAME_FILE);

    pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
            targetFile));

    logger.info("PDF file path: " + targetFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());

    document.open();

    PdfBuilder.assemble(document, pdfWriter, domain);

    document.close();
    pdfWriter.close();

    logger.info("End of PDF creation");

    map.put("file", targetFile.getAbsolutePath().toString());
}
```

The correct one is saved in `javax.servlet.context.tempdir` or in `C:/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/my_spring_app/pdf_file.pdf`.

#### How do I make the latter the one showed in the screen???

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I resolved it using the following code, and the file is now downloading instead of rendering a new pfd-view page (I prefer this).

```
protected final void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, 
           HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // IE workaround: write into byte array first.
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = createTemporaryOutputStream();

    // Apply preferences and build metadata.
    Document document = newDocument();
    PdfWriter writer = newWriter(document, baos);
    prepareWriter(model, writer, request);
    buildPdfMetadata(model, document, request);

    // Build PDF document.
    document.open();
    buildPdfDocument(model, document, writer, request, response);
    document.close();

    //Custom code start 
    String filestorePath = "/var/www/xxx/xxxxx/";
    String downloadfileNm = "DeliveryNote.pdf";
    String filePath = filestorePath+downloadfileNm;
    URL url = new URL("file:"+filePath);
    File file = new File(url.toURI());
    if (file.exists()) {
        response.setContentLength(new Long(file.length()).intValue());
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+downloadfileNm);
        FileCopyUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(file), response.getOutputStream());      
    }
    //Custom code end

    // Flush to HTTP response.
    //writeToResponse(response, baos);

}
```